# Get unique values in a column except values filtered from the original column - Excel Formula Only

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have been using

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($F$13:$F$1353, MATCH(0,COUNTIF($X$12:X12, $F$13:$F$1353), 0)),"")
```

and it work perfectly in order to bring unique values from a column with repeated values.

However I use a filter on the repeated values column "F" and when I deselect any item from the "F" filtered column I would like to have this item removed from the unique items list created. Couldn't figure out a formula to make this work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using this formula in `X13` copied down (or possibly `Y12` copied across). Try using this revised formula:

`=IFERROR(INDEX($F$13:$F$1353, MATCH(1,(COUNTIF($X$12:X12, $F$13:$F$1353)=0)*SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET($F$13,ROW($F$13:$F$1353)-ROW($F$13),0)), 0)),"")`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

The additional `SUBTOTAL(OFFSET` part works to exclude values that are not visible due to filtering

Comment: Perfect!! I really appreciate the help!

Comment: Hi Wouter. In additional to that would be possible to sort it in an alphabetical order? Thanks.